# Where can I put custom classes in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have some utility functions and Pagination function. I want to create classes named Utility and Pagination for these functions respectively, so that I can use these class function in more than one controllers.

So where can I put these class in my folder structure, and how can I access then?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can either create a new Folder called `Helpers` under the root and keep your classes physically there. I would keep my classes under a different namespace called `Helpers`

```
namespace MyProject.Helpers
{
  public class CustomerHelper
  {
        //Do your class stuff here
  }
}
```

To accees this in my other classes (Ex : Controllers) ,I can either use the fully qualified name

```
var custHelper=new MyProject.Helpers.CustomerHelper();
```

OR

add a `Import` statement at the top so that i can skip the fully qualified name

```
//Other existing Import statements here
using MyProject.Helpers;
public class RackController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
     var custHelper=new CustomerHelper(); 
     //do something with this  
     return View();    
  } 
}
```

If you think your Helper method can be used in another project also, You may consider to keep them **physically in a separate project**(of type class library). To use this in your project, Add a reference to this project and use it like what we did above (use either fully qualified name or use import statement)

Comment: @ppumkin - there are no coding practices in asp.net mvc that say you can't create your own folders or namespaces.  So no, it's not in-line with any coding practices, but it's not out of line with them.  It's just something that is in your own control.

Comment: Yea I ended up using the folder Helpers and they get reused everywhere now. So that was some good advice. And you are right @MystereMan there is not really a documented proper way but many good suggestion like this. Thanks

Comment: I used the "physically separate project" but I can't find my Class Library .config file in my main MVC application. Where can I find the settings file, I only get the .dll in \bin folder.

Comment: So where would the classes go that are created and don't fit under Models, or utility class. For ex, I have a class that's main function is to store two different data structures is returned by a method.

Comment: `Helpers` or `Utilities` etc. Again, there are no golden rules. Follow what make more sense to your team. IMHO, Consistency is important than names.

Comment: Between `var custHelper=new MyProject.Helpers.CustomerHelper();` and importing, is either one programatically quicker than the other?

Comment: @Shyju why your helper is not static??

Answer (score 13):

You can put your helper classes anywhere you find logical and convenient.

Personally I create a folder `Helpers` off of the main project folder.

You can use them anywhere, either by fully qualifying the class name or with a `using` statement.

In a Razor view, you would use

```
@using MyProject.Helpers
```

In a controller or model you would use

```
using MyProject.Helpers;
```

Answer (score 7):

Another approach could be creating a Base Controller class and adding your common logic there, and deriving your controller from your base controller.

```
public class MyBaseController:Controller
{
   public void CommonFunction()
    {
    }
}
```

Use like...

```
public HomeController:MyBaseController
{
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, but where would be the best place to keep it?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a new project,and then put the common classes into the project . If you want to use them,just Add Reference the project.

Answer (score 1):

Also, Please be sure to set the "Build Action" of your Class to "Compile".
In Visual Studio 2015, By default, every Class created within the App_Code (by right click -> Add -> Class) got "Content" as Build Action.